# Entity Framework - Select a fixed array of numbers as column of a query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do I select an `int[]` to as a column of a EF-to-SQL query? Suppose I have another column, and I would like to count the number of times these numbers appear... result would look something like this:

```
int[] nos = { 1, 2, 9, 4 };

-----------------------------------
nos   |   Count
 1    |     2
 2    |     1
 9    |     3
 4    |     1
```

If I have a column `SampleColumn` with values:

```
-----------------------------------
SampleColumn
     1
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     9
     11
     25
     9
     9
```

Something like this as my code (I honestly don't know how to approach it so I'm guessing it's like this):

```
var query = db.Table.Select(a => new { nos, a.SampleColumn.Count(b => b == nos } ).ToList();
```

I would like to be able to change `nos` as I prefer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can group the list.

```
int[] nos = { 1, 2, 9, 4 };

var result = nos.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new { x.Key, Count = x.Count() });
```

your code

```
 var query = db.Table.GroupBy(x => x.SampleColumn).Select(x => new { x.Key, Count = x.Count() });
```

Comment: Hey @Sinan, kindly look to my edits for additional details! Thanks!

Comment: @AwonDanag I'm added  a new line for you.